# How to re run queued job in resque using redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, resque, resque-scheduler

I am currently facing an issue in which I have scheduled job using Resque and redis but due to unavailability of any worker at the scheduled time for the job to run it got missed. Now the job remains in enqueued state.

Is there any way to update the timestamp of the job in redis so that it can be rerun again without scheduling another job to pick those jobs which are missed?

I tried to find out all the unique job_id which are missed, but unable to get the data in redis using the job_id

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to re-run the same job again you can try [resque-retry](https://github.com/lantins/resque-retry)

If you want to modify the redis key-val by yourself (NOT recommended due to consistency and race conditions)

you may try to run this via `redis-cli` using
`LINDEX` command,
this will pull the item value and save it for later,

next use `LREM` to remove it from the queue.

now update the timestamp from the previous step (it's just JSON strigify), now you have to push it back to the queue using `LPUSH` command.

for more about the `redis-cli` commands check [here](https://redis.io/commands/)